# How to enable "Show Touches" developer option from adb shell?

Tags: touches, screen-recording, adb

I need to show touches for a screenrecord to show a bug but don't want to navigate away into settings for fear that I'll lose my place and the bug will go away.

Anyone know if it's possible to enable this feature from the adb shell and if so, what I type in?

Answer (score 37):

This will enable show touches:

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:show_touches --bind value:i:1
```

And this disables it:

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/system --bind name:s:show_touches --bind value:i:0
```

Comment: Seems simpler to use `adb shell settings put system show_touches 1`. Note that you can get a list of all the system options with `adb shell settings list system`.